# Union of sets in spark querying cassandra

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-dataset

The table structure in cassandra:

```
identifier, date, set(integer)
```

What I want to achieve using Spark is grouping rows by the identifier and the date, and then aggregating all the sets value. I will be more clear by an example:

Raw data: (Consider letters representing integers)

```
id1, 05-05-2017, {a,b,c}
id1, 05-05-2017, {c,d}
id1, 26-05-2017, {a,b,c}
id1, 26-05-2017, {b,c}
id2, 26-05-2017, {a,b,c}
id2, 26-05-2017, {b,c,d}
```

Output:

```
id1, 05-05-2017, {a,b,c,d}
id1, 26-05-2017, {a,b,c}
id2, 26-05-2017, {a,b,c,d}
```

Since this is a set, I want unique values in aggregated results. I am using java and dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataframe has the columns you mentions you can do it like this:

```
df.withColumn("set", explode(col("set"))).groupBy("identifier", "date").agg(collect_set("set"))
```

Comment: this gives me {{a,b,c}, {c,d}} rather than {a,b,c,d}. I have already tried collect_set and collect_list

Comment: this works for me, but I have a question that whether exploding will be a performance hit or not? Can we do something like transforming the set of sets to a single set using map functions? I am new to spark, and could not find many examples for datasets and operations on them, docs doesn't contain more than one line

Comment: I think that it can be doable also without explode, and you have {{a,b,c}, {c,d}}. After that you apply a udf function to that column and transform it into {a,b,c,d}. I don't know it the explode will have a huge impact on performance. Please see the DAG that spark will execute it and take a look at the logical plan for the query.

Comment: I was using map/flatmap on the set of sets, how are they different from udf, i saw udf too, its like a custom function